# Which app opens ad webpages in my Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, browser, advertisements

Recently many ad pages are opened in default browser in my Windows 10. But I don't know which app opens these ad pages. How can I find out the app. Is there any log or software which shows the app's name or location?

Comment: Check your computer for adware and spyware. Malware bytes and HitMan pro are 2 tools you can use to identify adware. Also, check your browser's plugins. Any unwanted software in control panel, remove it.

Comment: @LPChip avg antivirus finds nothing

Comment: I said adware and spyware, not virus. AVG won't find adware and spyware. You need a different kind of scanner.